# Div overlapping when dynamically resizing (bootstrap css)

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two divs that have to alternate its size when clicked on them. My current approach is to remove and add classes via JQuery in order to do so.

When the first div is clicked and expanded to col-md-12, the second one is moved to the next row (desired behavior). The problem i am facing is with the second div, wich expands itself but instead of moving itself to the next row, it overlaps the first div.

The following code replicates my problem:

**HTML**

```js
    function Resize(div) {
        if ($(div).hasClass('col-md-6')) {
            $(div).removeClass('col-md-6').addClass('col-md-12');
        } else {
            $(div).removeClass('col-md-12').addClass('col-md-6');
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="row">
        <div id="div1" style="background-color: red;" class="col-md-6" onclick="Resize(this)">Text for div1</div>
        <div id="div2" style="background-color: blue;" class="col-md-6" onclick="Resize(this)">Text for div2</div>
    </div>

**Javascript/JQuery**
```

Comment: What browser are you using? For me it works.
Also, what Bootstrap version?

Comment: You only get 12 wide on the grid system.  If one of them is `-12` then is should be the only cell on the row.  The cells should all add up to 12.  Try using `col-md-8` and `col-md-4`.

Comment: Catalyst, I'm using bootstrap v3.0.0 and Google Chrome.

Comment: Nurdyguy, I know that that should be the desired behavior. Perhaps an example of my problem would describe it better: Starting with both divs with class col-md-6, I click on the second one and remove col-md-6 and add col-md-12 to it. Now i have '16', so i would expect the second div (with full 12) to be displayed on another row. Instead of that, both divs are displayed on the same row, and the second div (12) is overlapping the first div (6).